# IdentityServer4 server to server communication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have the following services & clients:

1. Identity server service.
2. API-1 service.
3. API-2 service.
4. JS client (Angular) that working with API-1 service.

API-2 also needs to work with API-1. I need to authenticate API-2 so it will be able to work with API-1 (retrieve data from API-1).

What I've done is getting a token form the IdentityServer4 service and using that token until the expiration date (and then getting a new one).

I read that usually in the server to server communication I need to use client_credentials, i.e use client id & secret.

The problem is that API-1 should support 2 clients, both the JS and API-2. So the question is, can I define, in controller level, to which client the controller is open?

I really want to do it right because I have 15 more services that need to consume data from API-1.

Thanks

Comment: What client is connecting to API-2 that would in turn use Some of API-1 controllers?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @aaronR the JS client.

Comment: @Jonas, not yet. At least not in a straight forward way. We have implemented API gateway approach which solved some of the problems.